# How to create abbreviations in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to abbreviate the first word in a 2 word string of values in dictionary.

input dictionary:

```
names = {
    'fire' : 'John Smith', 'water' : 'Steve Doe', 'earth' : 'Bob Smith'
}
```

I would like this to be the output.

output dictionary:

```
names_ab = {
    'fire' : 'J. Smith', 'water' : 'S. Doe', 'earth' : 'B. Smith'
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
names = {'fire': 'John Smith', 'water': 'Steve Doe', 'earth': 'Bob Smith'}

names_ab = {}
for element, name in names.items():
    first_name, last_name = name.split()
    names_ab[element] = '{}. {}'.format(first_name[0], last_name)

print(names_ab)
```

Which outputs:

```
{'fire': 'J. Smith', 'water': 'S. Doe', 'earth': 'B. Smith'}
```

If you need it to work for more names, you could use something like this:

```
for element, name in names.items():
    *first_names, last_name = name.split()
    names_ab[element] = '{}. {}'.format('. '.join(n[0] for n in first_names), last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

By tweaking the values in dict using `join` and `split`

```
names = { 'fire' : 'John Smith', 'water' : 'Steve Doe', 'earth' : 'Bob Smith will' }
{k:'. '.join([v[0],' '.join(v.split()[1:])]) for k,v in names.items()}
#Output:
#{'earth': 'B. Smith will', 'fire': 'J. Smith', 'water': 'S. Doe'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to extract that first capital letter in a *capturing group* and use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) referencing the captured group in a replacement string:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: names = { 'fire' : 'John Smith', 'water' : 'Steve Doe', 'earth' : 'Bob Smith' }

In [3]: pattern = re.compile(r"^([A-Z])[a-z]+")

In [4]: print({key: pattern.sub(r"\1.", value)
   ...:        for key, value in names.items()})
{'fire': 'J. Smith', 'water': 'S. Doe', 'earth': 'B. Smith'}
```

Note that this would also handle cases when there are more than two words/names defined in a string - like in case of "Amy Farrah Fowler".

Though, I can imagine a case to break this approach as well. Strictly speaking, this is a Natural Language Processing problem, but depends on what can the possible names be in your specific case as well.

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't works for more than two names.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo ah, we defined the "working" differently :) I've assumed the first word only to be abbreviated as "working". But, yeah, how to behave in this situation probably depends on the OP and possible inputs for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number of words you have in your dict as value.

```
names = {'earth': 'Bob Smith Jobs', 'fire': 'John Smith', 'water': 'Steve Doe'}

d = {}

for k in names:
    first, *rest = names[k].split()
    d[k] = '{0}. '.format(first[0]) + ' '.join(rest)

print(d)
```

But this works only in Python 3